# Rollback everything which has been updated in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 300 records if any error occurs on updation of last record (i.e 300) what my below piece of code will do is it going to rollback all changes ? or is it going to just rollback the last record.
**If it is going to rollback the last record, my objective is to rollback each and every thing that has been updated**

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN tran

        UPDATE users
        SET  
        password = p.password
        FROM @UpdatePassword p
        JOIN users u on p.userID = u.userID

    Commit tran

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    rollback tran
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

```
A transaction is a single unit of work. If a transaction is successful, all of the data modifications made during the transaction are committed and become a permanent part of the database. If a transaction encounters errors and must be canceled or rolled back, then all of the data modifications are erased.
```

In your case, you are explicitly starting a transaction, and either committing or rolling back the modifications based on your conditions. So, as long as there is an error occurring before the `COMMIT` statement can be processed, all modifications will be undone.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fb31/1).

Comment: I have to revert every change that has been done on getting any error, but **rollback tran** only reverts the change in which it gets error.Ex- If there is any error at last insertion or updation of record **rollback tran** will rollback the last record. But I have to revert all the changes

Comment: It will revert every single change made during the transaction up to the point where there is error. If you made other changes in other transactions they will not be affected. Does that help?

Comment: Nops let me explain it to you suppose I have to update 100 records, 99 records are updated successfully but on updation of last record (i.e 100) record I got some error.So now I want to revert all 99 records that were updated including the last one (i.e) 100.

Comment: The code which I have mentioned in the post is reverting the last changes made but it cannot revert all 99 changes. I hope you got it.Any help would be great!!!

Comment: Take a look at this and see how you can fit it to your situation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx